# How to download Postgres bytea column as file

Tags: file, postgresql, byte

Currently, i have a number of files stored in postgres 8.4 as bytea. The file types are .doc, .odt, .pdf, .txt and etc.

May i know how to download all the file stored in Postgres because i need to to do a backup.
I need them in their original file type instead of bytea format.

Thanks!

Comment: This is kind of unrelated, but please note that in postres 9.0 the default `bytea_output` changes from `encode` to `hex`.  Please see the [release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/release-9-0.html)

Answer (score 58):

One simple option is to use [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) command with [`encode`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-binarystring.html#FUNCTIONS-BINARYSTRING-OTHER) to hex format and then apply [`xxd`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_xxd.htm) shell command (with -p *continuous  hexdump style* switch). For example let's say I have jpg image in bytea column in samples table:

```
\copy (SELECT encode(file, 'hex') FROM samples LIMIT 1) TO
    '/home/grzegorz/Desktop/image.hex'

$ xxd -p -r image.hex > image.jpg
```

As I checked it works in practice.

Comment: Is it possible to not rely upon xxd for this? Isn't there a purely postgresql based solution to achieve the copy to?

Comment: @Marcel You could use `while read -N2 code; do printf "\x$code"; done <image.hex >image.jpg` instead xxd. It is not pure postgresql, but you need only bash for this. They say xxd is a part of vim package.

Comment: Instead of `'hex'`, you can use `'base64'`. The file will be smaller and the `base64` utility is more common than `xxd`.

Comment: use `psql -qt...` which will output just the field itself, then you can omit the `\copy`

Answer (score 7):

Here's the simplest thing I could come up with:

```
psql -qAt "select encode(file,'base64') from files limit 1" | base64 -d
```

The `-qAt` is important as it strips off any formatting of the output. These options are available inside the `psql` shell, too.

Comment: This solution worked for me when I added `-c` which according to the inline help tells psql to "run only single command (SQL or internal) and exit"

Comment: I needed to use `base64 -id`. (Unfortunately I can't suggest a change, because I only added 1 character.) See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730729/how-to-download-postgres-bytea-column-as-file/69517413#comment134662407_69517413

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
 COPY (SELECT yourbyteacolumn FROM yourtable WHERE <add your clauses here> ...) TO 'youroutputfile' (FORMAT binary)
```

Comment: This works; but the output needs additional processing. See [Binary Format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-copy.html#AEN77714)

Comment: You would have to trim off the binary headers and the footers. I downvoted, the answer isn't complete.

Answer (score 5):

**base64**

```
psql -Aqt -c "SELECT encode(content, 'base64') FROM ..." | base64 -d > file
```

**xxd**

```
psql -Aqt -c "SELECT encode(content, 'hex') FROM ..." | xxd -p -r > file
```

Comment: What if we want to get data directly? I want to copy data from database client (PgAdmin, HeidiSQL etc.) to a text file and save it to use, since i don't have access to the server.

Comment: I needed to use `-i` → `base64 -id` because `psql` outputs multiple newlines and `-i` allows to ignore non-alphabetic characters.

Comment: @postgresnewbie  psql is a database client,

Answer (score 3):

If you have a lot of data to download then you can get the lines first and then iterate through each one writing the bytea field to file.

```
$resource = pg_connect('host=localhost port=5432 dbname=website user=super password=************');

// grab all the user IDs
$userResponse = pg_query('select distinct(r.id) from resource r
                        join connection c on r.id = c.resource_id_from
                        join resource rfile on c.resource_id_to = rfile.id and         rfile.resource_type_id = 10
                        join file f on rfile.id = f.resource_id
                        join file_type ft on f.file_type_id = ft.id
                        where r.resource_type_id = 38');

// need to work through one by one to handle data
while($user = pg_fetch_array($userResponse)){
    $user_id = $user['id'];
    $query = 'select r.id, f.data, rfile.resource_type_id, ft.extension from resource r
                        join connection c on r.id = c.resource_id_from
                        join resource rfile on c.resource_id_to = rfile.id and rfile.resource_type_id = 10
                        join file f on rfile.id = f.resource_id
                        join file_type ft on f.file_type_id = ft.id
                        where r.resource_type_id = 38 and r.id = ' . $user_id;

    $fileResponse = pg_query($query);
    $fileData = pg_fetch_array($fileResponse);
    $data = pg_unescape_bytea($fileData['data']);
    $extension = $fileData['extension'];
    $fileId = $fileData['id'];
    $filename = $fileId . '.' . $extension;
    $fileHandle = fopen($filename, 'w');
    fwrite($fileHandle, $data);
    fclose($fileHandle);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work at least not on PG SQL 9.3. You need to strip leading `x` from the string and use `hex2bin` to get actual binary data.

Answer (score 1):

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE   
   l_lob_id OID;
   r record; BEGIN

  for r in
    select data, filename from bytea_table

   LOOP
    l_lob_id:=lo_from_bytea(0,r.data);
    PERFORM lo_export(l_lob_id,'/home/...'||r.filename);
    PERFORM lo_unlink(l_lob_id);   
    END LOOP;

END; $$
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: That's very nice solution btw! Thanks for your effort! This way we can get multiple rows instead of single one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this from a local windows, and not from the server, you will have to run every statement individually, and have PGAdmin and certutil:

1. Have PGAdmin installed.
2. Open cmd from the runtime folder or cd "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\runtime"
3. Run in PGAdmin query to get every statement that you will have to paste in cmd:

   SELECT 'set PGPASSWORD={PASSWORD} &&  psql -h {host} -U {user} -d {db name} -Aqt -c "SELECT encode({bytea_column}, ''base64'') FROM {table} WHERE id='||id||'" > %a% && CERTUTIL -decode %a% "C:\temp{name_of_the_folder}\FileName - '||{file_name}||' ('||TO_CHAR(current_timestamp(),'DD.MM.YYYY,HH24 MI SS')||').'||{file_extension}||'"'
   FROM table WHERE ....;

*Replace {...}*

It will generate something like:

```
set PGPASSWORD=123  psql -h 192.1.1.1 -U postgres -d my_test_db -Aqt -c "SELECT encode(file_bytea, 'base64') FROM test_table_bytea WHERE id=33" > %a% && CERTUTIL -decode %a% "C:\temp\DB_FILE\FileName - test1 - (06.04.2022,15 42 26).docx"
set PGPASSWORD=123  psql -h 192.1.1.1 -U postgres -d my_test_db -Aqt -c "SELECT encode(file_bytea, 'base64') FROM test_table_bytea WHERE id=44" > %a% && CERTUTIL -decode %a% "C:\temp\DB_FILE\FileName - test2 - (06.04.2022,15 42 26).pdf"
```

4. Copy paste all the generated statements in CMD. The files will be saved to your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Best I'm aware, bytea to file needs to be done at the app level.

(9.1 might change this with the filesystem data wrapper contrib. There's also a lo_export function, but it is not applicable here.)

Comment: Hi, can you provide me some example code to download bytea to file at the application level. Thanks!

Comment: Err.. You should have that code to display the files. Just save the stream instead.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy question is about download, not display the file.

Comment: @ManoharReddyPoreddy: Indeed. It's been a while since I wrote this but the reply was for the comment immediately above it. And I stand by my answer: if OP has (or had, since this was 8 years ago) code somewhere that writes browser headers and sends the raw file data to the browser, then fiddle with that code so it can write to a different stream instead -- such as a file.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy please share the code that works, this way it is more useful, as you can see we are all struggling to get this work correctly.

Comment: @ManoharReddyPoreddy: I'm sorry, I unfortunately don't have code that works for this, because I've never made the extremely dubious decision of storing binary data into a database. My point is that, assuming you have this issue, *you* already have code that works. To output the code as a file for a backup or something, reuse the code you've already written to display it in the browser. And if you're browsing this page because you're struggling to write the code to *display* the file, then you should revisit your database schema before it's too late and store an s3 uri instead.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy,  s3 or other is not an option for client. I think I got all the answers from the way you write your replies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [pgsql-fio](https://github.com/csimsek/pgsql-fio/) extension for this.

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION fio;

select fio_writefile('/home/<your_user>/Downloads', 'your_bytea_content');
```