# How do I copy a bytea column to a server file without PGCOPY or other header in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, copy, plpgsql, export-to-image

I am uploading images/zip files from client application via Java/JDBC to a bytea (NOT BLOB) column. But need to be able to export them to server side files. Postgres 13.

In plpgsql function I have:

```
EXECUTE format ('COPY (SELECT zipfile FROM file_upload) TO %L (FORMAT binary)', l_file_name);
```

But the first line is 'PGCOPY'. The copy command says there is no header for BINARY but there is :(

This has the same result:

```
COPY (SELECT zipfile FROM file_upload) TO PROGRAM 'cat > /tmp/dunc ' (FORMAT binary);
```

This seems a common requirement, but I can't find a simple resolution.

Similar to [How to export binary file with psql (without PGCOPY header)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335599/how-to-export-binary-file-with-psql-without-pgcopy-header) but from within a (privileged) database function

Comment: There is no simple solution. You will probably have to write code.