# How to download images from postgres bytea column using R or python?

Tags: python, r, postgresql

Basically, I have local postgres database with table called "person" and it has column called "image", which is a bytea column holding a .png image. I don't use postgresql and I want to download the images to be names from another column with the suffix ".png"

All the answers I have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730729/how-to-download-postgres-bytea-column-as-file) are postgres side answers and I really can't go with them. Is there is an authentic package in R or python that can download the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `R`:

```
# Packages we need
require("RPostgreSQL")
require('jsonlite')

# Create connection to database
pgConn <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), dbname="your_db", host='127.0.0.1')

# Query string - edit this to suit your needs
# Important thing here is that we're getting Postgres to base64 encode
#   the image data (converting it from binary to text)
thisQ = "SELECT encode(imageColumn, 'base64') AS image from test_table WHERE name='image';"

# Execute the SELECT query and fetch the results
resultSet = dbSendQuery(pgConn, thisQ)
resultData <- fetch(resultSet, n=-1)
dbClearResult(resultSet)

# Get the image data as text
imageData <- resultData$image

# Decode from base64 back to binary
imageDataDecoded <- jsonlite::base64_dec(imageData)

# Create a file connection and write the binary data to disk using mode "wb".
write.filename = file("/temp/file.png", "wb")
writeBin(imageDataDecoded, write.filename)
close(write.filename)
```

Comment: This worked till the usage of `jsonlite`. What worked for me is using base64enc::base64decode